# Why can I set these properties in the IDE but not in code?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I can set Maximum and Minimum Size height and width values for a DGV at design time but not in code. This won't compile, as "Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.MaximumSize' because it is not a variable":

```
dataGridViewPlatypi.MaximumSize.Height = dataGridViewPlatypi.Size.Height;
dataGridViewPlatypi.MinimumSize.Height = dataGridViewPlatypi.Size.Height;
dataGridViewPlatypi.MaximumSize.Width = dataGridViewPlatypi.Size.Width;
dataGridViewPlatypi.MinimumSize.Width = dataGridViewPlatypi.Size.Width;
```

If MaximumSize is not a variable, why can I modify it in the IDE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the error message more carefully:

> "Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.MaximumSize' **because it is not a variable"**:

[`Control.MaximumSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.maximumsize.aspx) is of the type `Size`, which is a value type.  The property returns a *copy* of a `Size` object and you then proceed to attempt to modify its properties.  Even if you could modify them it would accomplish nothing as you would only be mutating a copy.

You need to set the property to an entirely new value, not just change the properties of a copy.

```
dataGridViewPlatypi.MaximumSize = new Size(width, height);
```

Comment: Yep, so this works:

dataGridViewPlatypi.MaximumSize = new Size(dataGridViewPlatypi.Size.Width, dataGridViewPlatypi.Size.Height);
dataGridViewPlatypi.MinimumSize = new Size(dataGridViewPlatypi.Size.Width, dataGridViewPlatypi.Size.Height);

Comment: I know you know. But your eyes are not the only ones that will ever read this (probably).

Comment: @ClayShannon: Typically you convey that a given answer is correct by simply accepting the answer, but meh, no biggie.

Comment: Oh yes, I tried to do so, and it told me to wait four minutes, then I forgot to go back to it.